# How to get the position of null values in a vector in DolphinDB？

Tags: database, dolphindb

For example, I would like to get the position of null in the following vector.

```
a=1 NULL 2 3 6 NULL 2 NULL
```

I have tried the following script:

```
re=isNull(a)
index=array(int,0,1)
for(i in 1..size(a)){
    if(re[i]==true){
        index.append!(i)
        }
    }
print index
```

But the performance is poor when the vector is large, is there any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
at(a==NULL)
```